# Android CheckedTextView setChecked not working properly

Tags: android

populating data into listview (each item) in Adapter class

```
 // populate the data
 item.setText(megaItem.getName());
 item.setChecked(megaItem.getStatus());
```

to allow multiple selections of checkboxes in Activity using

```
 listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

Issue:

*Problem #1.* If, I `use above line` of code in Activity, then I `can check and uncheck all the items` I have in a `list`, but the problem is, I `can't see some of my items as checked` by default, as I mentioned `status true` for them in code

*Problem #2.* If, I `don't use above line` of code in Activity, then I `can see some of my items as checked` by default, as I mentioned status true for them in code, but problem is, I `can't check and uncheck any other item`, available in a `list`

Xml:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/checkedTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/CustomStyledRadioButton"
        android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple" />
```

getView() from Adapter class

```
@Override

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    //get the data for the item at this position
    MegaItem megaItem = getItem(position);

    //check if the view is being reused, otherwise inflate it
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.items_listview_layout,parent,false);
    }

    //get references to the UI elements to populate them
    item = (CheckedTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkedTextView);

    //populate the data
    item.setText(megaItem.getItemName());
    item.setChecked(megaItem.getStatus());

    //return the view to render on the screen
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: can you post your arrayadapter getView() method

Comment: @haresh posted check

Comment: experts please check this once

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
selectAll = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.selectAll);
selectAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
toggleAll(selectAll.isChecked());
    }
});



private void toggleAll(Boolean check)
{
int size = yourListView.getCount();
for ( int i=0; i<size ; i++ ) {
View v = yourListView.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
CheckedTextView tv = (CheckedTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.eventName);
tv.setChecked(check);
 }
 }
```

And in getView() Method.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {               
  CheckedTextView name = (CheckedTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.eventName);
       String[] result = item.split("/");                
  name.setText("txt");
  name.setChecked(true);
  return view;
```

Answer (score 0):

> set a checkMark property for your CheckedTextView in layout xml
>
> For example:
>   android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple

CheckedTextView is not just a checkbox with a text. You must also note, that CheckedTextView is not focusable, or clickable without some manipulation (since it was designed for ListView and therefore it's state must be controlled by ListView's setOnItemClickListener)

setChoiceMode should be set for a ListView. And checking of the row inside adapter's getView should be done via: listView.setItemChecked(position, value)

Comment: like I mentioned, my code works and doesn't work at very same time, due to listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE); line of code..